# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly unavailable for CellStyle?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagridtemplatecolumn

I'm trying to set an cellstyle of readonly depending the contents of another style.  Is this possible in XAML, seems trivial yet my code fails.

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Schedule" CanUserSort="True">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker DisplayDate="{Binding myschedule}" SelectedDate="{Binding myschedule}" >
            </DatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding boundname}" Value="testsiteshouldbereadonly">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I get the following error;

> Error 18  Cannot resolve the Style
>   Property 'IsReadOnly'. Verify that the
>   owning type is the Style's TargetType,
>   or use Class.Property syntax to
>   specify the Property.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't set IsReadOnly individually on cells, you can only set it on the whole column.
Try setting IsReadOnly="True" directly on the DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: I've tried setting the DataGridTemplateColumn, but only want to set  the cell not the column en-mass.

Answer (score 0):

You should set TargetType in the Style,Something Like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
          ....
     </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```